# renaming folders using a .txt file

Tags: command-line, bash, files, rename

I'm working in my terminal using bash trying to rename the folders:

```
1
2
3
4
5
```

I'd like to rename them according to a.txt file:

```
a 2
c 3
d 5
e 1
b 4
```

The order in the .txt file is completely random. I'm hoping to find a way where I can rename the folder so they become:

```
1 > e
2 > a
3 > c
4 > b
5 > d
```

Is there any way to do this?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: The question assumes there are no more then 26 fles to rename. Is that correct?

Comment: I've got 1 file and 200 folders to rename :(

Comment: Ah, that makes the question more interesting. Any chance on name clashes?

Comment: No, there should be. It's a whole bunch of protein models that a company made for me, and they have unique identifiers (that I just listed as numbers) such as ccVgk2214 and should be renamed to another unique identifier (SP_xxxx)

Comment: Are there any special characters in the filenames? Spaces? `*`?

Comment: I just have one file "info.txt", but the folders are named with small and capital letters and numbers. The new names that are listed randomly in the info.txt file are only SP_0000. So I guess _ is the only special character. No spaces.

Comment: @JacobVlijm I'm not sure I understand... I was trying to make the example more readable by using small letters and numbers. The real thing has got loads of combination possibilities and there should be no overlap. Does that explain it?

Comment: @JacobVlijm Super :)

Comment: Are all folder to be renamed on one (directory) level?

Comment: no no! I'd love to get an answer! Is it a problem for you that I'm on a macbook?

Comment: ehh... I've got no clue. How do I find out? Is python installed as default on my mac?

Comment: I tried typing "python" in my terminal. then it responds:           Python 2.7.10 (default, Oct 23 2015, 18:05:06) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 7.0.0 (clang-700.0.59.5)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

Comment: Should we close as off-topic now that OP has said (in the comments on @muru 's answer) that they use iOS, not Ubuntu?

Comment: @BharadwajRaju I have already voted to do so.

Comment: Super! I'm haning in here :)

Comment: @Ditte You use OS X and iOS. Why ask here, where it is off-topic? Ask at SuperUser or AskDifferent.

Comment: Sorry - I didn't know that. I tried at SuperUser. Will see if something happens in there

Answer (score 4, accepted):

***Assuming the names in the list do not include spaces***, other than *between* the names, the script below will rename folders from a textfile *recursively*. It will read the lines of the file, split them into two (new name, old name), rename occuring folders which are named by the *second* string in the line, into the *first* string in the line.

It will do this, as mentioned *recursively*, from bottom to top in the directory tree. This prevents issues in the script, attempting to rename folders in possibly already renamed parent folders.

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python
import os
import shutil

# -- set the (absolute) path to the targeted folder below
dr = "/home/jacob/Bureaublad/testfolder"
# -- set the path to the textfiles below
ren = "/home/jacob/Bureaublad/testfolder/renfile.txt"

renlist = [cpl for cpl in [l.split() for l in open(ren).readlines()] if cpl]
currnames = [r[1] for r in renlist]

for root, dirs, files in os.walk(dr, topdown = False):
    for dr in dirs:
        try:
            # look up the name, pass if not in the list
            i = currnames.index(dr)
        except ValueError:
            pass
        else:
            newname = renlist[i][0]
            shutil.move(root+"/"+dr, root+"/"+newname)
```

#### How to use

1. Copy the script into an empty file (in a *plain text* editor), save it as `rename.py`
2. In the head section of the script, set the real paths to the textfile and the directory
3. run it by the command (in a terminal):

   ```
   python /path/to/rename.py
   ```

#### Explanation

The script:

- creates a list of name- *couples*: newname/oldname
- using python's `os.walk()`, it looks through your directories recursively, from bottom to top.
- If the folder's name matches the second item of a name couple, it renames the folder into the first name.
- If the folder's name is not listed, it will be untouched.

Comment: is the script complete?

Comment: Yep, but still writing an explanation :)

Comment: @jacobvlijm Thanks! Do I just change the paths to my folders and text and then copy paste it in my terminal. Have never used python before

Comment: @Ditte nono, see description...

Comment: @JacobVlijm I saved your python script on my Desktop. Changed directory in the terminal to the desktop and wrote "python rename.py" but was prompted: File "rename.py", line 1
    {\rtf1\ansi\ansicpg1252\cocoartf1404\cocoasubrtf340
                                                      ^
SyntaxError: unexpected character after line continuation character

Comment: Does OS X use something other than `LF` for line endings?

Comment: @BharadwajRaju just remove the shebang (first line) probably a linux thing.

Comment: @JacobVlijm No, I myself have a shebang-included script which works fine on Linux, OS X and Win.

Comment: @BharadwajRaju could you remove it nevertheless, not sure if `env` is linux specific. Anyway, something in line one is bothering the shell. Just retested the script, works definitely and the python code is generic.

Comment: I removed the first line and got:                                                                      File "rename.py", line 5
SyntaxError: Non-ASCII character '\xe2' in file rename.py on line 5, but no encoding declared; see http://python.org/dev/peps/pep-0263/ for details

Comment: @Ditte In what application did you paste it? it should be in a plain text application. see http://stackoverflow.com/a/21639459/1391444

Comment: @JacobVlijm I tried to paste in both Word and TextMate

Comment: @Ditte save it as ascii!

Comment: @JacobVlijm I tried pasting the "# coding: utf-8" on the top of the script as suggested in the link you sent. And it works!!! Thanks so much!! I really really appreciate it and you taking the time to help me is amazing. Thanks again :)

Comment: Did that now, but just wanted to let you know how much I appreciated your help also :)

Comment: @JacobVlijm That's quite all right. I've got it saved by now :) Thanks again!

Answer (score 6):

You could use `xargs` with `mv`:

```
xargs -r -a /path/to/file.txt -L1 mv
```

(assuming you're in the directory where the files are located).

`xargs` converts input to arguments for a command.

- `-a foo` to read input from `foo`.
- `-L1` to use exactly one line of input per command invocation.
- `-r` to avoid running the command if the line is empty

For example, using `echo mv` instead of `mv` to show the commands being run:

```
$ xargs -r -a foo.txt -L1 echo mv
mv a 2
mv c 3
mv d 5
mv e 1
mv b 4
```

You can also use the `-p` option to make `xargs` confirm before running the command:

```
$ xargs -r -p -a foo.txt -L1 mv
mv a 2 ?...n
mv c 3 ?...n
mv d 5 ?...y
mv e 1 ?...mv: cannot stat ‘d’: No such file or directory
n
mv b 4 ?...
```

Comment: will not work by definition in a directory recursively, needs to be from bottom to top.

Comment: It says:xargs: illegal option -- r
usage: xargs [-0opt] [-E eofstr] [-I replstr [-R replacements]] [-J replstr]
             [-L number] [-n number [-x]] [-P maxprocs] [-s size]
             [utility [argument ...]]

Comment: @Ditte it's a legal option from at least 12.04: http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man1/xargs.1.html What version of Ubuntu are you using?

Comment: I'm on iOS. Is that a problem? I've used quite a lot of answers from in here, when I've been extracting info from large datasets and it usually works nicely. Hope that I haven't bothered you unnecessarily :(

Comment: Yes, that is a problem. Questions on non-Ubuntu systems should be asked on [unix.se]. As can be seen here, commands can be different.

Comment: So sorry! I'll try that instead. But thanks for trying to help me!

Comment: FWIW, try without the `-r` option as well. It shouldn't be a problem if empty lines are present (`mv` will just error out).

Comment: Still doesn't work. I won't waste any more of your time, I'll try the other forum. Thanks again :)

Answer (score 2):

There is one entry per line in the `a.txt` file, so the names listed do not contain `\n` (new line) char, right?

A line contains 2 names separated with a *space* char, so the names do not contain *space* char, right? (or another possibility would be to use fixed length for the names listed).

Give a try to this, if the names do not contain neither `\n` nor `space` chars:

```
awk '{printf("%s\0%s\0",$2,$1)}' a.txt | xargs -0 -L 2 mv
```

`awk` is used to reverse the order of names in lines read from `a.txt` file. `\0` is used to separate the names when they are printed to standard output.

`xargs` reads the standard input:

- `-0`: `\0` is used as separator for the elements read from standard input
- `-L 2 mv`: `mv` command is invoked with 2 parameters at a time.

The test:

```
$ ls -al
total 40
drwxrwxr-x  7 stacko stacko  4096 May 31 11:25 .
drwxrwxr-x 21 stacko stacko 12288 May 31 11:23 ..
drwxrwxr-x  2 stacko stacko  4096 May 31 11:25 1
drwxrwxr-x  2 stacko stacko  4096 May 31 11:25 2
drwxrwxr-x  2 stacko stacko  4096 May 31 11:25 3
drwxrwxr-x  2 stacko stacko  4096 May 31 11:25 4
drwxrwxr-x  2 stacko stacko  4096 May 31 11:25 5
-rw-rw-r--  1 stacko stacko    20 May 31 11:24 a.txt
$ cat a.txt
a 2
c 3
d 5
e 1
b 4
$ awk '{printf("%s\0%s\0",$2,$1)}' a.txt | xargs -0 -L 2 mv -v
'2' -> 'a'
'3' -> 'c'
'5' -> 'd'
'1' -> 'e'
'4' -> 'b'
$ ls -al
total 40
drwxrwxr-x  7 stacko stacko  4096 May 31 11:26 .
drwxrwxr-x 21 stacko stacko 12288 May 31 11:23 ..
drwxrwxr-x  2 stacko stacko  4096 May 31 11:25 a
-rw-rw-r--  1 stacko stacko    20 May 31 11:24 a.txt
drwxrwxr-x  2 stacko stacko  4096 May 31 11:25 b
drwxrwxr-x  2 stacko stacko  4096 May 31 11:25 c
drwxrwxr-x  2 stacko stacko  4096 May 31 11:25 d
drwxrwxr-x  2 stacko stacko  4096 May 31 11:25 e
```

Answer (score 2):

In the simple case you show above, where each line has two "words", the target directory and the new name, and where neither can contain any whitespace, you can simply do:

```
while read -r from to; do mv "$from" "$to"; done < file
```

That will read each line in `file` assign the first string (until the first whitespace) to `$from` and the rest of the line to `$to` and then run `mv` on each of them.